# Oracle Mybatis insert all

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I am trying to do a mybatis batch insert with Oracle.
I tried the insert all on my sql developer it works, but with Mybatis here, it complains.

How could I fix this?

```
<insert
        id="insertBatch"
        parameterType="java.util.List"
        keyProperty="id"
        keyColumn="COMMENT_ID"
        useGeneratedKeys="true">
        INSERT ALL
        <foreach collection="list" item="comment" index="index">
        INTO COMMENT (value1, value2)
        VALUES (#{comment.value1}, #{comment.value2})
        </foreach>
        SELECT *
        FROM dual
    </insert>
```

And I got error like this

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

#### The error may involve xxxx-Inline

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

> #### SQL: INSERT ALL        INTO   COMMENT (  VALUE1, VALUE2) VALUES    (    ?,    ?   )        INTO   COMMENT (  VALUE1, VALUE2  ) VALUES    (    ?,    ?    )       SELECT *   FROM dual;

#### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Sorry for my answer for mistaking your question, if you only insert data into one same table, why not just use `insert into`?

Comment: Since if I were to iterate through a whole bunch of "insert into", the performance will be bad, and that's why I am trying to do it in a batch mode.

Comment: Could you post all of the code please? This is just a syntax error.

Comment: The code above is the code I am using. Since there is confidential stuff, I cannot post all the things here. One thing is, I copy pasted the SQL built from mybatis and it works in the sql console.

Comment: Hmm, so check `?, ?,` if there is a `,` after last `?` or not.

Comment: I took care of that :). The value1, value2,.... was just for demo purpose

Comment: OK, so we assume all of this sql syntax is all right, but `Mybatis` gives us a  `SyntaxErrorException`, anyway it is weird for me. I think you may do more careful check for this cause we can not help you for just demo code.

Comment: Sure. It is super weird for me now as well. Still can't figure out.

Comment: Whats does COMMENT(value1,value2...) do

Comment: I modified the question a bit to clear some of the confusion

Comment: trying replacing `COMMENT (value1, value2)` with `(column1name,column2name,...)`

Comment: SQL syntax error: remove `SELECT * FROM dual`
 But it will generate a giant statement (and all associated drawbacks) growing with input list size. Indeed, using batch mode is better: `sessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH); /* iterate over List session.insert();*/  session.flushStatements();`